# Run maven task in Intellij for current project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In the IntelliJ config window for running maven tasks, I have to input the working directory, aka the maven project. Can I somehow input "the current project", based on the editor window I have open, so I don't have to duplicate a run task for each project?

I've tried `$ContentRoot$`, but those macros don't seem to work for Maven run tasks.

Comment: not directly the answer to your question, however i strongly recommend trying out the intellij plugin "maven helper". it allows you to right click on one of your projects/modules and run a maven goal directly from there. it also allows you to bind maven goals/run configurations to keyboard shortcuts and can be used configured to it runs the goal to the closest pom of your currently selected directory

Comment: Have Intellij recognized the current project as a maven project?